# Is metric $g$ a representation of Lorentz group? What decides it's transformation properties?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, group-representations, lorentz-symmetry

1. I am confused what representation of Lorentz group does a metric transform under?
2. How does it's transformation properties are decided?

Comment: The metric is a $(0,2)$ tensor of the Lorentz group. That tells you all you need to know about its transformation properties.

Comment: for "*How does it's transformation properties are decided?*" you might find my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230495/lorentz-invariance-of-the-minkowski-metric/230515#230515) helpful. It gives an intuitive reason as to why define the metric the way it is defined.

Comment: In fact the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ is not the irreducible representation of the Lorentz group if it represent massless particles.