# Confusion about notation

Tags: relativity

I'm currently self-teaching myself Relativity and I'm reading the book *Spacetime and Geometry*. I came across this expression:
[image: expression from the book]

What does the $\eta$ represent here? As I understand it the vector $\mathbf x$ is multiplied with the corresponding vector from the dual-space which is $\mathbf x^T$ to get the length squared of the vector. Does the $\eta$ represent a Matrix here? Why is it only applied to the transposed $\mathbf x$? I'm really confused about this and I think I'm just overlooking something, can someobody clarify this?

Comment: see [this answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230495/lorentz-invariance-of-the-minkowski-metric/230515#230515)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform That's a great answer, thank you! I really didn't understand the Matrix notation but seeing it in index notation made it clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\eta$ is the symbol for your metric tensor, usually Minkowski.  Basically, this says that the geometry of the space doesn't change in these transformations.

Comment: So $(\Delta x)^T \eta \Delta x$ is the same as $\eta_\alpha^\beta x^\alpha x_\beta$? Why is the metric tensor only applied to the $\Delta x$ or am I misunderstanding the notation?

Comment: The essence of the argument is that linear transformations (from $\Delta x$ to $\Delta x '$) don't change the metric.

Comment: This is a special case of $g_{ij}$, which is the metric tensor for all spaces, curved or flat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor   I say this because lots of authors don't always stick to the flat space convention, or there may be a typo.  You need to watch for context.