# Prove that two four-vectors and a four-tensor yield a scalar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relativity, tensor-calculus, covariance

I have to do a task for my special relativity class:

> Prove that: If $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}a^{\mu}b^{\nu}$ is a scalar for arbitrary four-vectors $a^{\nu}$, $b^{\nu}$, then $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}$ is a four-tensor.

I am totally confused about what to do since the answer seems too simple for me. The only possibility to make this a scalar is to let $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}$ be a 4x4-matrix when $a^{\nu}$ and $b^{\nu}$ are four-vectors, right?
I didn't have much linear algebra before, so I'd be thankful for any help on where to start and where to go.

Comment: I think it might just be a notation issue. It's not the standard convention, but I think here they say four-tensor meaning tensors over $\mathbb{R}^4$. Well, Minkowski$_4$.

Comment: Not any set of $4\times 4$ numbers is a tensor. There is more to being a tensor than that. You'll find [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/230515/84967) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to address your actual question the answer would be ~yes. Since its a scalar and both $a^{\mu}$ and $b^{\mu}$ are 4-vectors $\Gamma_{\mu \nu}$ must be a 2nd rank tensor. In the context of Special Relativity the underlying space is Minkowski space and thats what they mean by 4-tensor (This was already pointed out in the comments by Secavara) and these can be REPRESENTED by a 4x4 matrix.

It might seem a little abstract but that exact configuration is very commonly utilized in SR. For example when you define the inner product which grabs two 4-vectors and gives you a scalar you commonly do this $a \cdot b = a^{\mu} b_{\mu} = a^{\mu} g_{\mu \nu} b^{\nu}$ where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the Minkowski metric (4x4 representation). You can see that the last term is a special case of the object you have on your question.

As to how you can see that $\Gamma_{\mu \nu}$ is that kind of tensor you can perform a general coordinate transformation. Since a scalar should be invariant under such transformation you can check the only way that it can be satisfied is if Gamma is a 4-tensor.